# Pluralize iOS push notification

Tags: swift, xcode

I send localized push notification from API.

```
{
"id": "234",
"url": "https://...",
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "loc-key": "pushNotificationVoteKey",
            "loc-args": ["Jack", "5"]
        }
    }
}
```

And app receives push with title "`Jack has got 5 points`", but when Jack will get 1 point push notification will be the same "*`Jack has got 1 points`" except of "`Jack has got 1 point`"

Any chances pluralize background push notifications with `.stringdict` or any other ways to do it on mobile side?

Comment: Please share your code where you parse the push

Comment: @Koen There should be any code for background push notifications?

Comment: [Similar question here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/101992) shows that you can localise it with `.stringdict` but only for local notifications.

Comment: @Atlantis: Somehow that input must be parsed from `["Jack", "5"]` to `Jack has got 5 points`.

Comment: @Koen, just google `loc-key` and `loc-args` and what iOS does with them when it receives push notification.

Comment: @Koen I haven’t code for that. iOS search values by key in ‘’’Localizable.strings’’’ by itself and I just pass key and params into push

Comment: This page talks about plural rules for Stringsdict File Format: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/StringsdictFileFormat/StringsdictFileFormat.html

Comment: Or here: https://medium.com/@vitaliikuznetsov/plurals-localization-using-stringsdict-in-ios-a910aab8c28c

Comment: @Koen, those for formats in the string **in the app itself**. Question is about localisable strings in the **push notifications**, and why it doesn't use `.stringdict`. That completely different domain. Tangent, but different.